# Trouble figuring out data race in goroutine

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

I started learning go recently and I've been chipping away at this for a while now, but figured it was time to ask for some specific help. I have my program requesting paginated data from an api and because there are about 160 pages of data. Seems like a good use of goroutines, except I have race conditions and I can't seem to figure out why. It's probably because I'm new to the language, but my impressions was that params for a function are passed as a copy of the data in the function calling it unless it's a pointer.

According to what I think I know this should be making copies of my data which leaves me free to change it in the main function, but I end up request some pages multiple times and other pages just once.

My main.go

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "encoding/json"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "sync"

    "github.com/joho/godotenv"
)

func main() {
    err := godotenv.Load()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    httpClient := &http.Client{}
    baseURL := "https://api.data.gov/ed/collegescorecard/v1/schools.json"

    filters := make(map[string]string)
    page := 0
    filters["school.degrees_awarded.predominant"] = "2,3"
    filters["fields"] = "id,school.name,school.city,2018.student.size,2017.student.size,2017.earnings.3_yrs_after_completion.overall_count_over_poverty_line,2016.repayment.3_yr_repayment.overall"
    filters["api_key"] = os.Getenv("API_KEY")

    outFile, err := os.Create("./out.txt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    writer := bufio.NewWriter(outFile)

    requestURL := getRequestURL(baseURL, filters)

    response := requestData(requestURL, httpClient)

    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    for (page+1)*response.Metadata.ResultsPerPage < response.Metadata.TotalResults {
        page++
        filters["page"] = strconv.Itoa(page)

        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()

            requestURL := getRequestURL(baseURL, filters)

            response := requestData(requestURL, httpClient)

            _, err = writer.WriteString(response.TextOutput())
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatalln(err)
            }
        }()

    }

    wg.Wait()

}

func getRequestURL(baseURL string, filters map[string]string) *url.URL {
    requestURL, err := url.Parse(baseURL)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    query := requestURL.Query()
    for key, value := range filters {
        query.Set(key, value)
    }
    requestURL.RawQuery = query.Encode()

    return requestURL
}

func requestData(url *url.URL, httpClient *http.Client) CollegeScoreCardResponseDTO {
    request, _ := http.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, url.String(), nil)

    resp, err := httpClient.Do(request)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    var parsedResponse CollegeScoreCardResponseDTO
    err = json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&parsedResponse)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    return parsedResponse
}
```

I know another issue I will be running into is writing to the output file in the correct order, but I believe using channels to tell each routine what request finished writing could solve that. If I'm incorrect on that I would appreciate any advice on how to approach that as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You also cannot concurrently write to `writer`. Go types are not safe for concurrent use unless documented as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

goroutines do not receive copies of data. When the compiler detects that a variable "escapes" the current function, it allocates that variable on the heap. In this case, `filters` is one such variable. When the goroutine starts, the `filters` it accesses is the same map as the main thread. Since you keep modifying `filters` in the main thread without locking, there is no guarantee of what the goroutine sees.

I suggest you keep `filters` read-only, create a new map in the goroutine by copying all items from the `filters`, and add the `"page"` in the goroutine. You have to be careful to pass a copy of the `page` as well:

```
go func(page int) {
   flt:=make(map[string]string)
   for k,v:=range filters {
     flt[k]=v
   }
   flt["page"]=strconv.Itoa(page)
   ...
} (page)
```